# How to merge two array values with over riding the vales replacing empty values

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Suppose I have two arrays

```
var arr1 = [{
    "x": "Jan 2020",
    "y": 1
}, {
    "x": "Feb 2020",
    "y": 0
}, {
    "x": "Mar 2020",
    "y": 3
}, {
    "x": "Apr 2020",
    "y": 0
}, {
    "x": "May 2020",
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": "Jun 2020",
    "y": 0
}, {
    "x": "Jul 2020",
    "y": 7
}, {
    "x": "Aug 2020",
    "y": 0
}, {
    "x": "Sep 2020",
    "y": 9
}, {
    "x": "Oct 2020",
    "y": 0
}, {
    "x": "Nov 2020",
    "y": 11
}, {
    "x": "Dec 2020",
    "y": 0
}]

var arr2 = [{
    "x": "Feb 2020",
    "y": 2
}, {
    "x": "Apr 2020",
    "y": 4
}, {
    "x": "Jun 2020",
    "y": 6
}, {
    "x": "Aug 2020",
    "y": 8
}, {
    "x": "Oct 2020",
    "y": 10
}, {
    "x": "Dec 2020",
    "y": 12
}]
```

And I just want to merge like that

```
var res = [{
    "x": "Jan 2020",
    "y": 1
}, {
    "x": "Feb 2020",
    "y": 2
}, {
    "x": "Mar 2020",
    "y": 3
}, {
    "x": "Apr 2020",
    "y": 4
}, {
    "x": "May 2020",
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": "Jun 2020",
    "y": 6
}, {
    "x": "Jul 2020",
    "y": 7
}, {
    "x": "Aug 2020",
    "y": 8
}, {
    "x": "Sep 2020",
    "y": 9
}, {
    "x": "Oct 2020",
    "y": 10
}, {
    "x": "Nov 2020",
    "y": 11
}, {
    "x": "Dec 2020",
    "y": 12
}]
```

Comment: please add your try. what does not work?

Comment: What is the logic behind merging? Should the values in y be summed up? Should the highest / lowest value be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement custom logic, like

```
const resultArray = [...arr1]
for (let i in arr1) {
  const overrideValueInArray2 = arr2.find(item => item.x === arr1[i].x)
  if (overrideValueInArray2) {
    resultArray[i] = overrideValueInArray2
  }
}
```

`resultArray` should contained expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach to get the desired output:

- Combine both arrays into a single one. You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this.
- Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create an object having values from objects as keys which you wants to use for merging i.e `x` in your case.
- Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the resultant array.

```js
const arr1 = [{"x": "Jan 2020","y": 1}, {"x": "Feb 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Mar 2020","y": 3}, {"x": "Apr 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "May 2020","y": 5}, {"x": "Jun 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Jul 2020","y": 7}, {"x": "Aug 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Sep 2020","y": 9}, {"x": "Oct 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Nov 2020","y": 11}, {"x": "Dec 2020","y": 0}];
const arr2 = [{"x": "Feb 2020","y": 2}, {"x": "Apr 2020","y": 4}, {"x": "Jun 2020","y": 6}, {"x": "Aug 2020","y": 8}, {"x": "Oct 2020","y": 10}, {"x": "Dec 2020","y": 12}];

const result = Object.values(
  [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((r, c) => (r[c.x] = Object.assign({}, c), r), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Map` with a single loop for every array.

```js
let arr1 = [{ x: "Jan 2020", y: 1 }, { x: "Feb 2020", y: 0 }, { x: "Mar 2020", y: 3 }, { x: "Apr 2020", y: 0 }, { x: "May 2020", y: 5 }, { x: "Jun 2020", y: 0 }, { x: "Jul 2020", y: 7 }, { x: "Aug 2020", y: 0 }, { x: "Sep 2020", y: 9 }, { x: "Oct 2020", y: 0 }, { x: "Nov 2020", y: 11 }, { x: "Dec 2020", y: 0 }],
    arr2 = [{ x: "Feb 2020", y: 2 }, { x: "Apr 2020", y: 4 }, { x: "Jun 2020", y: 6 }, { x: "Aug 2020", y: 8 }, { x: "Oct 2020", y: 10 }, { x: "Dec 2020", y: 12 }],
    map = new Map,
    fn =  ({ x, y }) => map.set(x, map.get(x) || y),
    result;

arr1.forEach(fn);
arr2.forEach(fn);

result = Array.from(map, ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a structure like that, where you use `y: 0` as a placeholder and `arr2` is already correctly ordered. You can just [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over `arr1` and replace all elements with `y: 0`.

```js
const arr1 = [{"x": "Jan 2020","y": 1}, {"x": "Feb 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Mar 2020","y": 3}, {"x": "Apr 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "May 2020","y": 5}, {"x": "Jun 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Jul 2020","y": 7}, {"x": "Aug 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Sep 2020","y": 9}, {"x": "Oct 2020","y": 0}, {"x": "Nov 2020","y": 11}, {"x": "Dec 2020","y": 0}];
const arr2 = [{"x": "Feb 2020","y": 2}, {"x": "Apr 2020","y": 4}, {"x": "Jun 2020","y": 6}, {"x": "Aug 2020","y": 8}, {"x": "Oct 2020","y": 10}, {"x": "Dec 2020","y": 12}];

let i = 0;
const result = arr1.map(element => element.y ? element : arr2[i++]);

console.log(result);
```

This uses the fact that `0` is falsy, however you could also be more explicit if you like and replace `element.y` with `element.y == 0`. The `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse` syntax is called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).